# How to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2000

While working within SQL Server 2000, on one of the legacy systems, I ran the following query

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
where VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE '%XXXX%'
```

and got a result set with `VIEW_DEFINITION ---> CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_ISLocation]  AS ....`

Now the problem is, there is no view with that name (`vw_ISLocation`) in the database. The only view with the same TEXT has a different name `vw_Location`.

Does anyone know how this could be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible explanation is that the object was originally created with the name `vw_ISLocation` and that it was subsequently renamed using `sp_rename`. This is documented behaviour (from [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238878%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)):

> Renaming a stored procedure, view or trigger will not change the name
>   of the corresponding object name in the syscomments table. This may
>   result in problems generating a script for the object as the old name
>   will be inserted from the syscomments table into the CREATE statement.
>   For best results, do not rename these object types. Instead, drop and
>   re-create the object by its new name.

(the definition in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` is based on the same data as `syscomments`)

Comment: More than likely seem to have been the issue, I replicated it. Thanks